# Is there a bug with flex 4.5.1 form states?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, states

The following code example should produce hello world (in two rows) yet it produces "world hello" instead ...

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="state1" />
        <s:State name="state2" />
    </s:states>

    <s:Form excludeFrom="state2">
        <s:Label text="hello" />
        <s:Label text="world" includeIn="state1" />
    </s:Form>
</s:Application>
```

Replacing the `Form` with `HGroup` of `VGroup` seems to work as expected...

I know this is not the recommended usage of a `Form` but I tried to use it only because it supports defaultButton out of the box.

Shouldn't it work?

**EDIT:**
It seems that BorderContainer has the same issue, but mx:Form seems to work well